# Dinamically creating table and apend a subtotal row at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a table with an Ajax Query on a modal hide event with this code.

```
$('#modalarticulos').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {;

    sel_articulos =  $("input[name='check_art']:checked").map(function ()
    {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
console.log(sel_articulos);
$("#sel_articulos tbody").empty();
ii =0;
var tbody = $('#sel_articulos tbody');
$.each(sel_articulos, function(ii, sel_articulo) {
    var tr = $("<tr id=artrow["+ii+"]>");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo $_SERVER_ADDR . PUBLIC_PATH .'presupuestos/buscart/'; ?>",
        data: { 'id':sel_articulos[ii]},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $("<td id='id["+ii+"]'>").html(response["id"]).appendTo(tr);
            $("<td id='tipart["+ii+"]'>").html(response["tipart"]).appendTo(tr);
            $("<td id='codart["+ii+"]'>").html(response["codart"]).appendTo(tr);
            $("<td id='desart["+ii+"]'>").html(response["desart"]).appendTo(tr);
            $("<td id='canart["+ii+"]'><input type='number' id='cantidad["+ii+"]' min='0' max='999' step='1' class='input-mini text-right cantidart' value='1'>").appendTo(tr);
            $("<td id='precio["+ii+"]'>").html(response["precio"]).appendTo(tr);
            $("<td id='subtot["+ii+"]'>").html("<label id='subtotal["+ii+"]' class='text-success subtotal'>"+response["precio"]).appendTo(tr);
            tbody.append(tr);
            },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occurs!');
            }
       });
   });
$('#sel_articulos > tbody').after(<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><label class='subtotalg'>SUB-TOTAL</label></td><td></td><td><label id='subtotalsi' class='text-success subtotalg'>Subtotal</label></td></tr>;
})
```

**question 1** the problem that i am facing is that i need the last row (the one being added after, the body) to be inside the body itself, now it is being created outside it and by consequence its not being cleared by the:

```
$("#sel_articulos tbody").empty();
```

**Question 2** : in addition to that i would like to know if there is another way of arranging the creation of that table to make it more efficient. thank you.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be doing an ajax call for every single row in your table.  That is horribly inefficient.  Try doing a single ajax call to return an array of data, then loop through that to populate your tablerow.

Comment: @Scottie Thanks, i'll try to do some research and improve it. About the last <tr>, do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`$.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) adds an element after the selected element. You need [`$.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which adds an element inside the selected element.

Do this:

```
$('#sel_articulos > tbody').append(<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><label class='subtotalg'>SUB-TOTAL</label></td><td></td><td><label id='subtotalsi' class='text-success subtotalg'>Subtotal</label></td></tr>;
```

**UPDATE**

As per your comment, you need to add it after the rows are added. Just check if you're adding the last row first.

```
 $.each(sel_articulos, function(ii, sel_articulo) {
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "<?php echo $_SERVER_ADDR . PUBLIC_PATH .'presupuestos/buscart/'; ?>",
         data: { 'id':sel_articulos[ii]},
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(response) {
             $("<td id='id["+ii+"]'>").html(response["id"]).appendTo(tr);
             $("<td id='tipart["+ii+"]'>").html(response["tipart"]).appendTo(tr);
             $("<td id='codart["+ii+"]'>").html(response["codart"]).appendTo(tr);
             $("<td id='desart["+ii+"]'>").html(response["desart"]).appendTo(tr);
             $("<td id='canart["+ii+"]'><input type='number' id='cantidad["+ii+"]' min='0' max='999' step='1' class='input-mini text-right cantidart' value='1'>").appendTo(tr);
             $("<td id='precio["+ii+"]'>").html(response["precio"]).appendTo(tr);
             $("<td id='subtot["+ii+"]'>").html("<label id='subtotal["+ii+"]' class='text-success subtotal'>"+response["precio"]).appendTo(tr);
             tbody.append(tr);

             // Check if added last row
             if(ii == sel_articulos.length - 1){
                  $('#sel_articulos > tbody').append(<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><label class='subtotalg'>SUB-TOTAL</label></td><td></td><td><label id='subtotalsi' class='text-success subtotalg'>Subtotal</label></td></tr>;
            }
         },
         error: function() {
             alert('Error occurs!');
         }
     });
 });
```

However I would do what @Scottie said in the comments and get all the table data in one request, rather than one for each row. That would make this a lot easier because you could just append it after all the other ones have been appended.

Comment: This way the <tr> its created inside the tbody but before the rows generated in the ajax query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Deferred (and Promise) to manage it better, and indeed the ajax in jQuery would return a Promise like interface, so you can try:

```
var data = {};
var promise = $ajax.({
    ...
    success: function (response) {
         // Collect your data here
         data['id'] = response['id'];
         ....
         // This means success and the done callbacks in the deferred will be executed.
    }
    ...
});

// The done call back will be executed after your ajax success callback is called
promise.done(function () {
    // now use your data to create a table
    ...
});
```

Learn more about jQuery promise and defer:
https://api.jquery.com/promise/
https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Solved this by setting async : false in my ajax call... by default it is true.

Comment: async: false may not be a good idea since that's blocking. 
A good thing about ajax is that you can still allow users to interact with your web page while getting things from server. 
But of course, if you need to block user interaction when getting the data from table anyway, then this maybe fine..